# Error in elasticsearch indexing using mongo river and PlainElastic.Net

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, plainelastic.net, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to index my mongodb collection using PlainElastic.Net client and also using CURL. But I am failing miserably in both the attempts.

My .net object is as follows

```
<BsonIgnoreExtraElements>
Public Class QueryReadyProduct

<BsonIgnore()>
<JsonIgnore()>
Property _id As Object
Property CustomerId As Guid
Property ProductId As Guid
Property CategoryId As Guid
Property CustomHierarchyId As Guid

<BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)>
Property Name As String
```

End Class

When migrated to mongodb I get an additional `_id` property field

With PlainElastic.net the following are the steps I am trying to execute

```
Dim data As String = "{
  \"type\": \"mongodb\",
  \"mongodb\": {
    \"db\": \"brandviewdata\",
    \"collection\": \"queryreadyproducts\"
  },
  \"index\": {
    \"name\": \"mongoindex\",
    \"type\": \"products\"
  }
}"

Dim jsonData As String = serializer.ToJson(data)

Dim indexR As String = connection.Put(New IndexCommand("_river", "mongodb", "_meta"), "{}")
Dim mappingResult As String = connection.Put(New PutMappingCommand("_river", "mongodb"), jsonMapping)
Dim indexResult As String = connection.Put(New IndexCommand("_river", "mongodb", "_meta"), jsonData)
```

JSON Mapping is as follows

```
{
    "queryreadyproduct": {
        "type": "object",
        "_all": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "Name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "CustomerId": {
                "type": "binary",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "ProductId": {
                "type": "binary",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "CategoryId": {
                "type": "binary",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "CustomHierarchyId": {
                "type": "binary",
                "null_value": "",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error in ElasticSearch Log

```
[2013-06-07 10:42:21,763][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Ranger] [_river][0], node[hKe8cliXSPmHcySUUmhJLg], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [index {[_river][mongodb][_meta], source["{ \"type\": \"mongodb\", \"mongodb\": { \"db\": \"brandviewdata\", \"collection\": \"queryreadyproducts\"}, \"index\": {\"name\": \"mongoindex\", \"type\": \"products\" }}\""]}]
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Malformed content, must start with an object
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:477)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:450)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:327)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:532)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Also some times in the elastic search log

```
[2013-06-07 09:42:04,122][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Ranger] no river type provided for [_river], ignoring...
```

I am really stuck at this point. Unable to find a solution. Any help to proceed further is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake I was doing

In this line of code

```
 Dim jsonData As String = serializer.ToJson(data)
```

I am trying to serialized a valid Json Object "data"

When I pass "data" instead of "jsonData" in the following line of code

```
 Dim indexResult As String = connection.Put(New IndexCommand("_river", "mongodb", "_meta"), jsonData)
```

It's performing the indexing with out any error.